# Multiple regex options with C# Regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Assume I have this:

```
Regex.Replace("aa cc bbbb","aa cc","",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

But I also need to ignore white-spaces. So, I found an option `IgnorePatternWhitespace`, but how can I add several options to one regex.Replace?
Something like:

```
Regex.Replace("aa cc bbbb", "aa cc", "", 
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase + RegexOptions.IgnorePatterWhitespace);
```

**Update:**
Thanks for answers but this option does not seem to work: here's a test example:

```
Regex.Replace("aa cc bbbb", "aacc", "", 
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatterWhitespace);
```

Comment: "Does not seem to work" isn't very informative. What kind of behavior specifically are you after?

Comment: This simply does not makes sense as a question - especially once you see what the accepted answer is, but even outside of that context!

Comment: use & instead of +, Regex.Replace("aa cc bbb", "aa cc","", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace & RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

Comment: vb.net version = Regex.Replace("aa cc bbb", "aa cc", String.Empty, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace And RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

Comment: `|` operator works well: [**C# working code demo**](http://rextester.com/JXN20372) ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **IgnorePatternWhitespace**
>   Eliminates unescaped white space from the pattern and enables comments
>   marked with #. However, the IgnorePatternWhitespace value **does not** 
>   **affect or eliminate white space in character classes.**

so:

```
string result = Regex.Replace("aa cc bbbb","aa|cc","",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Trim();
```

Answer (score 90):

Use [bitwise OR (`|`)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17zwb64t.aspx)

```
Regex.Replace("aa cc bbbb",
                "aa cc",
                "",
                RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatterWhitespace);
```

Comment: @user194076, if you are expecting regular expression "aacc" to match "aa cc" in "aa cc bbbb", you are interpreting the RegexOptions incorrectly. You have to use something like "aa\s?cc" to match that i.e. use \s? to match optional whitespace.

Regex.Replace("aa cc bbbb","aacc","",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase |

Answer (score 13):

```
Regex.Replace("aa cc bbbb","aa cc","",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatterWhitespace);
```

Use the `|` operator.

**Edit :**

You got it completely wrong. `RegexOption.IgnorePatterWhitespace` ignores the whitespace in the regex so that you can do :

```
string pattern = @"
^                # Beginning of The Line
\d+              # Match one to n number but at least one..
";
```

You however think that ingoring whitespace makes `"aa cc bbbb"` into `"aaccbbbb"` which is thankfully wrong.

Answer (score 8):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa332136%28v=VS.71%29.aspx):

> A bitwise OR combination of RegexOption enumeration values.

So just use `OPT_A | OPT_B`

Answer (score 3):

You can have as many RegexOptions as you like, just "OR" them with "|".

For example...

```
RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
```